# Java library to map HTTP status code to description?

Tags: java, error-handling, http-status-codes

I'm in the situation where I'm writing custom error pages for a webapp (primarily to reduce information disclosure from the servlet container's default error pages).  Since I *need* an error page for each error status code, I'm going to have to have a sensible response for each code.  As far as I can tell, these error pages don't have to be particularly user-friendly, but simply redirecting everything to a single "it went wrong" error page is going to make diagnosing problems very difficult.

So I'm wondering if there is a Java library that provides a good mapping between HTTP status codes and a brief human-readable description of them (ideally a 2-4 word "summary", for use as a page title, as well as a 1-3 sentence message expanding on the summary).  Then I could just use this in a JSP to provide some feedback on the class of the error.  If not I'm sure I can write one myself, but if wheels have been invented I'm happy to use them.

Comment: need this in javascript..... I also object to the question closure. It was unfortunately worded. The people voting to close it should be encouraged first to edit the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> So I'm wondering if there is a Java
>   library that provides a good mapping
>   between HTTP status codes and a brief
>   human-readable description of them
>   (ideally a 2-4 word "summary", for use
>   as a page title, as well as a 1-3
>   sentence message expanding on the
>   summary).

Yes, [Apache Commons HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) has this functionality. The [`HttpStatus`](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpStatus.html) class has the same list of `int` constants that you'll find elsewhere, but it also has a [`static String getStatusText(int)`](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpStatus.html#getStatusText%28int%29) method that returns a human-readable description of the status code.

Here is the `Maven` dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Example code:

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpStatus;

String responseMessage = HttpStatus.getStatusText(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
System.out.println(responseMessage);
```

Prints:

```
OK
```

Comment: Which jar do I have to add to build path to use this method? I've added all of them and none of them work.

Comment: For v4 of this apache project: httpComponents, look at my answer below

Answer (score 10):

Latest apache http components v4+ ( httpCoponents )

Introduces the following:
HttpStatus as an enum containing all of the httpStatuses

For their description use:
EnglishReasonPhraseCatalog.INSTANCE.getReason(code, Locale.ENGLISH);

Where your status code == code, eg: 200

For example:

```
HttpStatus.SC_FORBIDDEN == 403
EnglishReasonPhraseCatalog.INSTANCE.getReason(403, Locale.ENGLISH) == "Forbidden"
```

Comment: Yep, `org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpStatus` is [no longer supported](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/); [org.apache.http.HttpStatus](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.4/org/apache/http/HttpStatus.html) should be used instead. But  [EnglishReasonPhraseCatalog.getReason()](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.4/org/apache/http/impl/EnglishReasonPhraseCatalog.html#getReason(int,%20java.util.Locale)) is need to get an HTTP status code's phrase; that info is no longer part of a `HttpStatus` object.

Answer (score 7):

I think you might like the Spring solution:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html

Comment: org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.name() can be used for the status code description and HttpStatus.value() for the status code number

Comment: `HttpStatus.valueOf(status_code)?.getReasonPhrase()` returns the pretty print.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe the easiest solution is to use next function:

```
httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase()
```

It returns exactly what's needed.

Answer (score 4):

Abstract class '[HttpURLConnection](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)' provides you with constant int values for all HTTP status codes. Its documentation has a short verbal description for each constant. You could make yourself a simple enum with these values and strings, and use that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Jersey (or have it on your classpath), the `javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status` enum includes human-readable "reasons" from the HTTP spec, e.g. `Response.Status.fromStatusCode(404).toString()` gives `"Not Found"`.

Comment: Why does `Response.Status.fromStatusCode(405)` return `null`?

Comment: @Stefan: I just spent a while banging my head against this too. NOT_ALLOWED is just not included in Response.Status enum. Note that there is in fact an interface http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.StatusType.html that lets you create your own status types. Useful, but only if whatever you're using it for will accept a StatusType instance rather than a Status instance...

Comment: @Stefan it exists in `ClientResponse.Status` and in `Responses.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED_TYPE`. I ended up creating my own enum.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [HttpStatus JSP Tag Libray](https://github.com/ethauvin/HttpStatus):

```html
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="hs" uri="http://erik.thauvin.net/taglibs/httpstatus" %>
<html><head>
<title><hs:code/> <hs:reason default="Server Error"/></title>
</head>
<h1><hs:reason default="Server Error"/></h1>
Cause: <pre><hs:cause default="Unable to complete your request."/></pre>
```

Specifically, as shown in the example above, the `<hs:reason/>` tag is used to display the reason phrase (*human-readable description*) for the current HTTP status code in the page's title and first heading.

Additionally, the `<hs:code/>` tag is used to display the current HTTP status code and the `<hs:cause/>` tag to display the message from the exception that caused the error.

Comment: Please go into detail why your library solves this problem, specifically. Whenever posting a code snippet it helps to explain what it is doing, and why it addresses the issue.