# jsp get http error description

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, http-error

Is there a way to get the tomcat default description of a HTTP error in a jsp page?
I can get the Status code (404, 500, 505), like:

```
<%=response.getStatus() %>
```

but I didn't find how to get the description:[see the printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifyA9.png)

Have you any ideas?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you have to look at this question, may help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302072/how-can-i-get-the-http-status-code-out-of-a-servletresponse-in-a-servletfilter

Comment: I saw it, but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone is interested I found the answer on stackoverflow :
[Java library to map HTTP status code to description?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637750/java-library-to-map-http-status-code-to-description)

You will need to download the [jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar) of [Appache Commons HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/)
and import it to your jsp page:

```
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.httpclient.*"%>
```

And with the method getStatusText you can get the Http Error description: 
`<%=HttpStatus.getStatusText(response.getStatus())%>`.